# Spring data jpa -Child entity having another foreign key representing same table field not inserted

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities. User.java, DirectReport.java

```
User.java
*************************************
@Entity
@Table(name = "User")
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class User{
 .....
 ......
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.DETACH,
        CascadeType.REMOVE  })
@JoinColumn(name = "user_code", referencedColumnName = "code")
public List<DirectReports> getDirectReports() {
    return directReports;
}

public void setDirectReports(List<DirectReports> directReports) {
    this.directReports = directReports;
}
}

DirectReport.java
****************************
@ManyToOne(optional=true)
@JoinColumn(name = "directreport_code", referencedColumnName = "code", insertable = false, updatable = false)
public User getDirectReport() {
    return directReport;
}

public void setDirectReport(User directReport) {
    this.directReport = directReport;
}

@Column(name="directreport_code")
public String getDirReportCode() {
    return dirReportCode;
}

public void setDirReportCode(String dirReportCode) {
    this.dirReportCode = dirReportCode;
}
```

Data is inserted in child table. user_code column is also updated. but directreports_code field is set as null. can anyone pls help?

Edit: Updating the database as below:

```
UserService.java
***********************************
User userVar;
DirectReports dr;
   for (String str : model.getDirectReportsCode()) {
   userVar = repository.findByCodeIgnoreCase(str);
   System.out.println("userVar "+userVar.getCode());
   dr = new DirectReports();
   if (userVar != null) {
   dr.setDirReportCode(userVar.getCode());
   list.add(dr);
    }
}
    System.out.println("list " + list);
    model.setDirectReports(list);
    toBeApprovedModel2 = getMainRepository().save(model);
    getMainRepository().flush();
    postApprove(toBeApprovedModel2);
```

Note: model.getDirectReportsCode() is a string. I am iterating, finding the corresponding user, add it in a list and set it in model object. I can see the value of dirReportCode field while "getMainRepository().save(model)".

Comment: how u r updating in database, share the code?

Comment: Can you post the whole code of your classes? `DirectReport` looks a bit strange.

Comment: Save child records first and set the same to parent while saving.

Comment: I have updated the question. Please have a look. @Balasubramanian

Comment: @pleft: regarding `DirectReport` only field declarations are left.
@PRATHAPS: I think cascading will take care of this. please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: update user object in database. e.g. -> userVar.saveAndflush(..) method

Answer (score 0):

In your `UserService.java` try setting the `userVar` also on your `dr` object

```
if (userVar != null) {
   dr.setDirReportCode(userVar.getCode());
   dr.setDirectReport(userVar);  // <----- do this

 //rest of your code
```

**Update**

In your `User` entity change the following:

```
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.DETACH,
        CascadeType.REMOVE  })
@JoinColumn(name = "user_code", referencedColumnName = "code")
public List<DirectReports> getDirectReports() {
    return directReports;
}
```

To (note the addition of the `mappedBy` attribute and the removal of `@JoinColumn`):

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.DETACH,
            CascadeType.REMOVE  }, mappedBy="directReport")
public List<DirectReports> getDirectReports() {
    return directReports;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Tried it now. And even now, directreport_code field is set as null

Comment: I have updated my answer, take a look please, you should better revisit how `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToOne`, take a look at an easy example here: https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-many-relationship-example-annotation/

Comment: And one question for you: Why in your `DirectReport` class you have a `User` object defined as `directReport` (see your `public User getDirectReport()` method) This is causing so much confusion to you (and to us)!

Comment: I have two fields in `DirectReport` entity. One is `user_code` which is saved by `List<DirectReports>` in `User` entity properly. Another one is `directreport_code` which has `@ManyToOne` relationship with user. This `directreport_code` value is set as null. I am facing problem in that only.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of constructing the directreport on server side, I constructed the object it client side itself and saved in which I dint face any problem. Yet, I dono why constructing the object on server side doesn't work.